# Retweet, reply and favorite in iOS 5 Twitter with the Accounts framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, twitter

I have integrated iOS 5 Twitter in my application. I am able to send tweets by `TWTweetComposeViewController` with the integration of Twitter and Accounts framework.

Now I want to retweet, reply and favorite in iOS 5 with the help of Accounts framework.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use following code for retweeting.

```
- (void)_retweetMessage:(TwitterMessage *)message
{
    NSString *retweetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweet/%@.json", message.identifier];
    NSURL *retweetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:retweetString];
    TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:retweetURL parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];
    request.account = _usedAccount;

    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        if (responseData)
        {
            NSError *parseError = nil;
            id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&amp;parseError];

            if (!json)
            {
                NSLog(@"Parse Error: %@", parseError);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"%@", json);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Request Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
}
```

[Taken From Here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/05/twitter-framework-tutorial/)

Good Luck.

Comment: yes , thanks it works for retweet , now i am trying for favorite and reply

Comment: i will defiantly accept ur answer , i have up vote it already , but  i  am trying for favorite and reply , thats why i am waiting .:)

Comment: Actually its very easy you have to modify existing function with https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/favorites/create/%3Aid this url with minor appropriate changes. Go through documentation https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

Comment: I insist you to add your methods to my answer for Favorite and reply so other can get help easily if you wish.

Answer (score 9):

friends Jennis 's answer helps me for finding my solutions and answer is :

**1) For Retweet  and Favorite**

*This is a class method for sending request , you have to pass different URL's for retweet and Favorite.*

```
    + (void)makeRequestsWithURL: (NSURL *)url {
    // Create an account store object.
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    // Create an account type that ensures Twitter accounts are retrieved.
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    // Request access from the user to use their Twitter accounts.
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if(granted) {
            // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
            NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            // For the sake of brevity, we'll assume there is only one Twitter account present.
            // You would ideally ask the user which account they want to tweet from, if there is more than one Twitter account present.
            if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
                // Grab the initial Twitter account to tweet from.
                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];


                // Create a request, which in this example, posts a tweet to the user's timeline.
                // This example uses version 1 of the Twitter API.
                // This may need to be changed to whichever version is currently appropriate.
                TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

                // Set the account used to post the tweet.
                [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

                // Perform the request created above and create a handler block to handle the response.
                [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                    iOS5Twitter *twitter5 = [[iOS5Twitter alloc] init];
                    [twitter5 performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayText:) withObject:output waitUntilDone:NO];
                    [twitter5 release];                }];
            }
        }

    }];

}
```

**URL for Retweet :**
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/retweet/id_str.json.xml
**URL for Favorite:**
https://api.twitter.com/1/favorites/create/id_str.json
https://api.twitter.com/1/favorites/destroy/id_str.json

**2) Code for Reply**

```
       + (void)makeRequestForReplyWithSelectedFeed:(NSString *)status inReply2:(NSString *)updateID{
    // Create an account store object.
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    // Create an account type that ensures Twitter accounts are retrieved.
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];



    NSString *trimmedText = status;
    if ([trimmedText length] > 140.0) {
        trimmedText = [trimmedText substringToIndex:140];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
    [params setObject:trimmedText forKey:@"status"];
    if (updateID > 0) {
        [params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", updateID] forKey:@"in_reply_to_status_id"];
    }

    // Request access from the user to use their Twitter accounts.
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if(granted) {
            // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
            NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            // For the sake of brevity, we'll assume there is only one Twitter account present.
            // You would ideally ask the user which account they want to tweet from, if there is more than one Twitter account present.
            if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
                // Grab the initial Twitter account to tweet from.
                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];


                // Create a request, which in this example, posts a tweet to the user's timeline.
                // This example uses version 1 of the Twitter API.
                // This may need to be changed to whichever version is currently appropriate.
                   TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"] parameters:params requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

                // Set the account used to post the tweet.
                [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

                // Perform the request created above and create a handler block to handle the response.
                [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                    iOS5Twitter *twitter5 = [[iOS5Twitter alloc] init];
                    [twitter5 performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayText:) withObject:output waitUntilDone:NO];
                    [twitter5 release];                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

**method Call :**

`[iOS5Twitter makeRequestForReplyWithSelectedFeed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tweetMessage.text ]inReply2:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",selectedFeed.id_str]];`

I have created a class iOS5Twitter and implement a class method , if you want to do it in your controller , kindly replace `delegate` by `self`

Comment: Hi PJR.. I am getting `code = 34; message = "Sorry, that page does not exist";` while passing https://api.twitter.com/1/favorites/create/id_str.json url. Can you please help me to do this?

Comment: @ShahPaneri it may be an issue of change in library. i think now a days twitter has changed its library so look at that, it may help you.

Comment: I found the issue. I have not authenticated the user so it was giving me the error. B.T.W. thanks for answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `TWRequest` class instead of `TWTweetComposeViewController` to access tweets, retweets, reply and favorite. For more information use these links. [Link1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios) and [Link2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWRequestClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010942)

Comment: thanks , but which url and parameters i have to pass for retweet , reply and favorite ?