# How to do a Reply on a Tweet on an iPhone twitter app (MGTwitterEngine)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, twitter, ios-simulator, mgtwitterengine

How to do a Reply on a Tweet on an iPhone twitter app (MGTwitterEngine)?

Can Any one give me link or source code to reply the the tweet?

Thanks,
Tejas

Comment: use post status/update, supply  in_reply_status_id parameter with tweet id together, start tweet with @nameuser who authorized tweet..some docs: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update

Comment: this should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308690/retweet-reply-and-favorite-in-ios-5-twitter-with-the-accounts-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your Response But i have done with Reply on tweet using FHSTwitterEngine.

https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine